# after adding certificate to xcode project

Tags: swift4, swift4.1

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/ZeusTheme
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E38072A3-CFE2-4E44-86F8-D7C817114210/ZeusTheme.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: the problem is appear like this how to slove this problem

Comment: have you tried with a clean build and deleting derived data?

Comment: The problem is occured after I add a new certificate to my project.

Comment: Sure, but try a clean and delete derived data after then to build project.

Comment: I clean and build it.its working perfectly.thank you very much for quick response.

Comment: accept my answer as it works for you so that it will be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a clean your project and delete derived data after then build project.